Confused about the definition of a multivariate ODE
I am currently reading through a paper for my master's thesis, but I keep getting confused by the example the author uses for the central algorithm.
I believe that once I understand this, the rest should fall into place eventually as well, but I am stuck.
So, this is the ODE in question (I can't seem to find an option to format formulas...):

My (admittedly shallow) understanding of ODEs is that they would take a form like f'(x) = a*f(x) + b or something similar. I could understand if the first row also involved the derivative of x1, but the way it is written, it just doesn't make sense to me...
Could anyone help me understand why this ODE is written the way it is, especially why the first row is so different from the other two?

Would it make more sense if it was written like this: $f(t) = -h(t), g'(t) = f(t), h'(t) = g(t)$?

I feel tempted to just replace $x_1$ with $-x_3$ in equation (2). Then we have a system of ODEs involving only $x_2$ and $x_3$ and we can forget about $x_1$.

$x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are all functions of $t$. Let me replace $x$'s with $f,g$ and $h$ as in my comment, to remind you that they are functions. The system is then
\begin{align}
f(t) &= -h(t)\tag{1}\\
g'(t) &= f(t)\tag{2} \\
h'(t)& = g(t)\tag{3}
\end{align}
Differentiating $(3)$ with respect to $t$ gives us $h''(t) = g'(t) \stackrel{(2)}{=} f(t) \stackrel{(1)}{=}-h(t).$ This is a well known ODE that has general solution $h(t) = A\cos t+B\sin t$, so $g(t) = h'(t) = -A\sin t+B\cos t$ and $f(t) =  -h(t) = -A\cos t-B\sin t$, for any constants $A$, $B$.

Ah, I was not aware that it is a well known ODE... I figured it was just a random example the authors thought up. Thank you for your answer, knowing the origins should help me understand it better.

@AntonReinecke, if you specified initial conditions, then it is possible to define sine and cosine by this system, see here.
